# call a function func1of file1.js from func2 of file2.js file and func1 uses a global variable declared in file1.js

Tags: javascript, function, variables, global

Let me rewrite the question. I have tested the code and the issue should be reproduceable.
There are two html files, test1.html and test2.html, and two js files: file1.js and file2.js.

test1.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello, It's test1 page!</p>
    <button onclick = "func0()">populate contacts</button>
    <script src="file1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, file1.js is included in test1.html.

test2.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <p>Turn to test2 page now!</p>
    <button onclick = "func2()">Try me</button>
    <script src="file1.js"></script>
    <script src="file2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

both file1.js and file2.js are included in test2.html.

file1.js:

```
"use strict";

var contacts = [];

function func0() {
    contacts.push('mike');
    contacts.push('tom');
    contacts.push('joe');
    window.location.replace("test2.html");
}

function func1(msgType, uuid) {
    if(isArrayEmpty(contacts)) {
        alert("contacts is empty");
        return;
    }
    contacts.forEach(function(contact) {
        console.log(contact + " sends msg with type = " + msgType + ", and msg id = " + uuid);
    });
}

function isArrayEmpty(array) {
    if (!Array.isArray(array) || !array.length) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

file2.js:

```
"use strict";

function func2() {
    func1('OPEN', '1234');
}
```

As you can see, func1 of file1.js was invoked by func2 of file2.js. But the variable contacts declared in file1.js was empty.
Thus the loop over contacts were not actually done. contacts should not be empty as func0 of file1.js populated values to it. func0 was invoked by clicking "populate contacts" button in test1.html.

That's actually happened in my read code.

Seek an answer here.

Edit on 03/31/2021: can anybody help on this?

Comment: *"Here func0 is called initially"* - Not in the code shown it isn't.  In the code shown three functions are defined, none are ever invoked.  Can you provide a more complete example, preferably as a runnable code snippet, demonstrating the problem?  (At a glance it seems like the problem is *probably* that you're trying to treat an object like an array...)

Comment: unsure how you push to an object. My guess the actual problem is with the real code, not this fake code. Let me bet there is.an Ajax/Fetch call involved here.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @David, you are right. in the real code, there are more lines for that. Here I edited the question by adding a line for that.

Comment: @mikej1688: In the updated code still nothing ever calls `func1` or `func2`.  (The latter calls the former, but since nothing calls the latter it doesn't make a difference.)  We can't spot problems in code you're not showing us.  Instead of trying to make your fake code look more like real code, take some time to make an actual real example that demonstrates the problem.  In doing so you may even find the problem and not need our help, but if you don't find it then an actual example will at least allow us to help you.

Comment: @David, func1 in file1.js is invoked by func2 in file2.js. A moment ago, I added one line to invoke func2 in file2.js. Here I only tried to write a fake code to show what the real code does. The real code is complicated and it's not worth showing the detail. Sorry.

Comment: @mikej1688: And even the most cursory test of the code you're showing us reveals that [it works](https://jsfiddle.net/7h86eacu/).  (The only changes made were (1) commenting "..." lines, (2) adding a `console.log` for testing, and (3) defining `uuid` so it doesn't produce an error.)  So what isn't working?  We can appreciate that the real code is more complex, but without an example which actually demonstrates the problem there's nothing we can do to help because there's no problem to be solved.

Comment: @David: are you putting all the code in one js file? In my case, they were in separate js files.

Comment: @David, I rewrote the sample code. The issue would be reproduceable.

Comment: @Rojo, can you take a look at it now?

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the function for that. YOu haven't called the function. So, that is the reason.

Comment: I tested it this way, var contacts = ['mike', 'peter', 'tom']; that is, the variable was declared and instantiated together, then when func2 of file2.js calls func1 of file1.js, contacts was not empty - that's what I expected. However, if I only declared it like, var contacts = []; then it was empty even if it was populated later on (but before invocation from file2). That's the part I don't understand.

Comment: can you make a little clear statement? I called the function.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an object type error, because contact var is an object (`{}`) you can't use the `.push` method with it because the object doesn't have it. Instead of using a regular object, I suggest you use an array: `var contacts = [];`

Comment: good catch. Actually it was in real code. var selectedContacts = []; I simplified it here and shown the logic.

Comment: I rewrote the sample code, can I take a look now?

Answer (score 1):

test1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello, It's test1 page!</p>
    <button id="populate">populate contacts</button>
    <script type="module" src="file2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

test2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <p>Turn to test2 page now!</p>
    <button id="test2">Try me</button>
    <script type="module" src="file2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

file1.js

```
"use strict";

var contacts = [];

function func0() {
    contacts.push('mike');
    contacts.push('tom');
    contacts.push('joe');

    ///////////////////// Local Storage || JSON.stringify()

    localStorage.setItem('contacts',JSON.stringify(contacts));  

    /////////////////////

    window.location.replace("test2.html");
}


//////////////////////// from Local Storage

var getContacts = localStorage.getItem('contacts');
var arr =  JSON.parse(getContacts)  // get an array

////////////////////////

function func1(msgType, uuid) {
    if(isArrayEmpty(arr)) {
        alert("contacts is empty");
        return;
    }
    arr.forEach(function(contact) {
        console.log(contact + " sends msg with type = " + msgType + ", and msg id = " + uuid);
    });
}

function isArrayEmpty(array) {
    if (!Array.isArray(array) || !array.length) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


//////////////

export{func0,func1};
```

file2.js

```
"use strict";

import{func0, func1} from './file1.js';

function func2() {
    func1('OPEN', '1234');
}

// BUTTON: Populate Contacts [test1.html]

var button = document.getElementById('populate');
if(button != null) {
    button.addEventListener('click',function(){
        func0();
    });
}


// BUTTON: Try Me [test2.html]

var button2 = document.getElementById('test2');
if(button2 != null) {
    button2.addEventListener('click', function(){
        func2();
    });
}
```

Output:

[image: ######]

Comment: thanks for the answer. I rewrote the sample code. It can be run now and the issue can be reproduced. Can you try it and let me know the result.

Comment: use localStorage or sessionStorage

Comment: the doc says, for those storages, "the keys and the values are always in the UTF-16 DOMString format, which uses two bytes per character. As with objects, integer keys are automatically converted to strings." I expect to save the array as an Array, or object as an Object.

Comment: @mikej1688 JSON.stingify() and JSON.parse() would help you get the results you want

Comment: Yeah, I understood that. However, I'd like to share some common objects across multiple html pages. For example, in the first html page, I created a connection object,  ```var stompClient = null;
var socket = new SockJS('/websocket');
 stompClient = Stomp.over(socket); ```, here stompClient is a global variable connecting to the backend server. I'd like to reuse this variable in other html pages, rather than recreating a new one for every page. I don't know if it's good for saving it as a string into the localStorage or not.